# How to exit main thread in Python and make the child threads continue in background

Tags: python, multithreading

My objective here is to make the child threads run in background while the main threads should start them and then exit:

I tried the below code:

```
import time
import logging
import threading

logging.basicConfig(filename="threading.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

def worker(count):
    for c in range(count,-1,-1):
        threadname = threading.currentThread().getName()
        threadcount = threading.active_count()
        threadnames = threading.enumerate()
        logging.debug("Child thread: {} continuing with threadcount {} {} and counter value: {}".format(threadname,threadcount,threadnames,c))
        time.sleep(2)

mainthread = threading.currentThread().getName()
print ("Starting main thread:",mainthread)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=(10,))
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
time.sleep(5)
print ("Attempting to close main thread:",mainthread)
```

But as soon as the main thread exits i think the child thread also exits since i have this output in the threading.log(which i created from child thread)

```
DEBUG:root:Child thread: Thread-1 continuing with threadcount 2 [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 1160)>, <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 10232)>] and counter value: 10
DEBUG:root:Child thread: Thread-1 continuing with threadcount 2 [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 1160)>, <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 10232)>] and counter value: 9
DEBUG:root:Child thread: Thread-1 continuing with threadcount 2 [<_MainThread(MainThread, started 1160)>, <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 10232)>] and counter value: 8
```

I know using join() would not be the answer since the main thread would block.

I dont want the main thread to block at all.

Is there a solution to the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do that, this is not a problem about python, but a problem about system.

No matter child thread or child process will exit if main process exit. This was controlled by system, so you can do nothing on it.

Or you can change your mind, why you have to exit your main process?

Answer (score 0):

You can put main process to run as a daemon and listen for some variables or something like that (you can try with json)
If you will close main process all other threads etc... will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

you ought to explain why you want this behavior because it shouldn't be necessary, by making the main thread wait with `join` it becomes dormant, not really consuming any more power/memory than if it wasn't there.
However the `t1.setDaemon(True)` is what makes the child threads stop when the main process does, comment out or remove this line and it should do what you want. but this it nor good practice.
example:

```
import time
import logging
import threading

logging.basicConfig(filename="threading.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

def worker(count):
    for c in range(count,-1,-1):
        threadname = threading.currentThread().getName()
        threadcount = threading.active_count()
        threadnames = threading.enumerate()
        logging.debug("Child thread: {} continuing with threadcount {} {} and counter value: {}".format(threadname,threadcount,threadnames,c))
        time.sleep(2)

mainthread = threading.currentThread().getName()
print ("Starting main thread:",mainthread)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=(10,))
#t1.setDaemon(True) # do not set daemon
t1.start()
time.sleep(5)
print ("Attempting to close main thread:",mainthread)
```

Comment: your code is still making the main thread wait for the child code to complete, in my machine.

Comment: How are you checking that? Do you mean because the console doesn't close? Because the other threads are still attached to the same console hence why it doesn't close